# Combined amps available

Tags: amperage

If I have 5 AA batteries powering a locking device, what would be the maximum combined available amps available?

I know that 1 AA battery has 50mA but I do not know if I can just combine that value to get 250 mA.

Comment: Research "how does voltage and current combine with batteries in series versus parallel?"

Comment: lperry - Hi, (a) "*I know that 1 AA battery has 50mA*" Please [edit] your question and add a source for that claim, as it isn't true for any AA batteries I've ever seen. (b) The question is written as a hypothetical, but with some very specific details e.g. mentioning a locking device. If you are doing a real design then please include more context and details, in order to avoid possible X-Y problem situations, where the *real* problem is something else than what you are asking. Thanks.

Comment: lperry, you will need to respond to have much chance at getting a useful response. What is the locking device? Or failing a specific product, what are the specifications for the locking device?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you connect the batteries. If they are connected in series, you get the sum of all the voltages and the current (amps) of a **single** cell. If you hook them up in parallel, exactly the opposite happens: you get the voltage that a **signle** cell would output and the sum of the amps that all the cells output together.

So you have two options:

1. Connect the batteries in parallel and get 1.5V (I assume that's the voltage of one of your AA batteries) and 5 * 50mA = 250mA
2. Connect them in series and get 5 * 1.5V = 7.5V and 50mA

I don't know what the operating voltage of your device is to tell you which arrangement is needed in your case but these are your only options if you keep these batteries.

P.S.: 50mA of maximum current sounds like very little for a AA battery. I've powered a lot of power-hungry things using them

Comment: A cheap 'Super Heavy Duty" AA battery is old-fashioned Carbon-Zinc. If it was sitting in a store for a few years then it might produce a max current of only 50mA. a Name-Brand AA Alkaline battery can produce a current of 500mA for a while. A Name-Brand AA Ni-MH rechargeable battery can produce a current of 2500mA for a while.